# How does this string manipulation work in python?

Tags: python, string, decimal

```
 PriceStr=group[2]
 price=Decimal(sub(r'[^\d.]', '', PriceStr))
```

In this part of code, a variable string for money is being converted into Decimal.
What does the second line of this code actually mean?
Why is the 'sub', the 'r', the apostrophes, the '^' etc. needed?

Comment: sub was probably imported from https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub

Answer (score 2):

They delete all symbols from the string except numbers and dots,

for example
'$1,346.9 total' is converted to '1346.9'

Answer (score 0):

In Python `r'string'` means *raw string*, i.e. string where escape sequences are not valid. Compare for example:

```
print(r'foo bar\n')
print('foo bar\n')
```

In the second case `\n` interpreted as a notation for new line, while at the raw string it is just a slash and a letter `n`. Find out more about raw strings for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l).

The method `sub` has been imported from module `re`. At the top of your code you likely will find this line:

```
from re import sub # (or `from re import *`)
```

In my opinion it is better to `import re` and after access `sub` as `re.sub`, this way it is unambiguous.

The first argument of `sub` is a regular expression. Regular expressions (regex) are a big topic, you can find excellent resources to understand them [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) or and [here](http://www.rexegg.com/). What this particular regex does:

- defines a character class (between square brackets `[` and `]`)
- tells that this character is not a digit (`\d` means digit, same as `0-9`), and `^` means negation (not)
- then it tells that this character can be anything (dot `.` in regex means any character

The so called regex engine will look for matches of this one character pattern, for example in `abc123` it will have 3 matches: `a`, `b` and `c`. The second argument of `sub` tells what to replace these matches with. Here you tell replace with nothing (empty string, i.e. nothing between 2 quote marks: `''`). The third argument of `sub` provides the string you want to do this operation on. Then the result is passed to a method or class called `Decimal`, you can look this up in your code and find out what it does.

*Not part of the answer, but general advices how to handle better similar cases:*

If you want to understand a basic code like this, you can import its methods and try them one-by-one, or temporarily add `print()` statements, reload the module and call the methods. For example let's say your module is called `pricecalculator`, and is in a directory with the same name or in a file `pricecalculator.py`, then you go to that directory, open a Python shell, and type:

```
import imp
import pricecalculator
from pricecalculator import *
```

Then you can call any method from this module. Let's say you are wondering what is the variable `group`, and what is its third element? Then add the line `print('group: ', group)` or `print('type of group: ', type(group))` above the lines in your post, and reload the module:

```
imp.reload(pricecalculator)
from pricecalculator import *
```

Then you call the method where the code takes place, and you will see the content of the variable printed.

Also if you see a method and you are wondering what it does, try to find out where does it come from, which module, and look up the documentation of the method. For example:

```
import re
# see the documentation:
help(re.sub) # press `q` to return to shell

from re import *
# find the module for a method:
sub.__module__
```

And try to experiment directly with the methods directly in the shell, read the docs, try things and understand the error messages. [Here is a guide](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/standard_exceptions.htm) what each types of errors mean.

Finally, before asking a question here, always think: is there a chance that the answers will help someone else? Try to formulate the title and the question accordingly.